# problem in creating client with redis on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I get this error when I run the code:

ClientClosedError: The client is closed
at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Main0120\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:409:31)
at Commander.commandsExecutor (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Main0120\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:170:154)
at Commander.BaseClass. [as publish]

```
const redis = require("redis");
const CHANNELS = { TEST: "TEST" };
class Pubsub {
    constructor() {
        this.publisher = redis.createClient();
        this.subscriber = redis.createClient();
        this.subscriber.subscribe(CHANNELS.TEST);
        this.subscriber.on("message", (channel, message) => {
            this.handleMessage(channel, message);
        });
    }
    handleMessage(channel, message) {
        console.log(`message recieved. channel: ${channel}. message: ${message}`);
    }
}
const testPubsub = new Pubsub();
testPubsub.publisher.publish(
    CHANNELS.TEST,
    "this is a message that published"
);
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

it was because of a problem in redis version.
use: npm i redis@3.1.2